# Emacs: Is it possible to fold (collapse/expand) json objects/collections?

Tags: json, emacs, folding

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1.

Suppose I have big json file. And it's very comfortably if I can folding (collapse/expand) any node of this json. I do this by Notepad++.

Here example:

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to do same in Emacs? 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, install json-mode.

Comment: [This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7361/2710) suggests using the `yafolding` package.

Comment: "yafolding" - exactly what is needed.Thanks

Comment: @AndrewSwann yes "yafolding" is wotk but has one problem. When json has > 2 nested elements than commad "yafolding-hide-element" work VERY SLOW (about 15 second  hide element). So the question is: Has alternative of package "yafolding" ?